# Web API (Python, Flask) with middleware and JWT for requests authentication raises DecodeError('Signature verification failed')

Tags: flask, request, jwt, decode, flask-restful

I'm having trouble decoding a token that I receive through the header of my request.

Application:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import jsonify
from flask_restplus import Resource, Api
from helpers.load import get_env as _
from middleware.environment_middleware import EnvironmentMiddleware
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = _('DATABASE_URI')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = _('DATABASE_URI')
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = _('SECRET_KEY')
app.config['JWT_SECRET_KEY'] = _('JWT_SECRET')
app.wsgi_app = EnvironmentMiddleware(app.wsgi_app)

jwt = JWTManager(app)
api = Api(app)
jwt._set_error_handler_callbacks(api)
```

Middleware Class:

```
from werkzeug.wrappers import Request, Response, ResponseStream
from helpers.load import load_db_env
from flask_jwt_extended import get_jwt_identity, jwt_required, verify_jwt_in_request
import jwt


class EnvironmentMiddleware():
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        request = Request(environ)
        if request.headers:
            params = load_db_env(request.headers.get('Whitelabel'))
            jwt.decode(request.headers.get('Authorization').replace('Bearer ', ''), params['JWT_SECRET'], algorithm='HS256')
            return self.app(environ, start_response)

        res = Response(u'Unauthorized.', mimetype='application/json', status=401)
        return res(environ, start_response)
```

**load_db_env** brings a dict with all params from my database according with the 'whitelabel' parameter including the **JWT_SECRET** and my **environ** brings all Response data, headers, etc that I need for authentication.

But for some reason I can't decode and find the informations inside the Bearer Token from the request for validate and identify the user.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/bela/dev/bela/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jwt/api_jwt.py", line 63, in decode
    decoded = super(PyJWT, self).decode(jwt, key, verify, algorithms,
  File "/home/bela/dev/bela/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py", line 115, in decode
    self._verify_signature(payload, signing_input, header, signature,
  File "/home/bela/dev/bela/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py", line 186, in _verify_signature
    raise DecodeError('Signature verification failed')
jwt.exceptions.DecodeError: Signature verification failed
```

I hope I was clear, I'm from Brazil and my english is not the best.

Obrigada! :*